# Getting WGS84 lat lon bounds from VRT file

Tags: gdal, coordinate-system, gdalwarp, extents, vrt

I have vrt files generated using gdalbuildvrt that reference GeoTiffs referenced using the NZTM coordinate system.

Is there an easy way to determine the bounds as WGS84 latitude longitude coordinates?

I assume this should be possible with a few GDAL commands from the command line prompt.

Example vrt file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <VRTDataset rasterXSize="11340" rasterYSize="8505">
       <SRS>PROJCS["New Zealand Transverse Mercator 2000; NZGD 2000",GEOGCS["unknown",DATUM["unknown",SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.2572221010002,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT[,0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",173],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["false_easting",1600000],PARAMETER["false_northing",10000000],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]]]</SRS>
       <GeoTransform>1.0839978833333333e+006, 4.2333333333333298e+000, 0.0000000000000000e+000, 4.9020021166666662e+006, 0.0000000000000000e+000,-4.2333333333333298e+000</GeoTransform>
       <VRTRasterBand dataType="Byte" band="1">
          <HideNoDataValue>1</HideNoDataValue>
          <ColorInterp>Red</ColorInterp>
          <SimpleSource>
             <SourceFilename relativeToVRT="1">CF04_GeoTifv1-02.tif</SourceFilename>
             <SourceBand>1</SourceBand>
             <SourceProperties RasterXSize="5671" RasterYSize="8505" DataType="Byte" BlockXSize="5671" BlockYSize="17" />
             <SrcRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="5671" ySize="8505" />
             <DstRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="5671" ySize="8505" />
          </SimpleSource>
          <SimpleSource>
             <SourceFilename relativeToVRT="1">CF05_GeoTifv1-01.tif</SourceFilename>
             <SourceBand>1</SourceBand>
             <SourceProperties RasterXSize="5671" RasterYSize="8505" DataType="Byte" BlockXSize="5671" BlockYSize="17" />
             <SrcRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="5671" ySize="8505" />
             <DstRect xOff="5669" yOff="0" xSize="5671" ySize="8505" />
          </SimpleSource>
       </VRTRasterBand>
       <VRTRasterBand dataType="Byte" band="2">
          <HideNoDataValue>1</HideNoDataValue>
          <ColorInterp>Green</ColorInterp>
          <SimpleSource>
             <SourceFilename relativeToVRT="1">CF04_GeoTifv1-02.tif</SourceFilename>
             <SourceBand>2</SourceBand>
             <SourceProperties RasterXSize="5671" RasterYSize="8505" DataType="Byte" BlockXSize="5671" BlockYSize="17" />
             <SrcRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="5671" ySize="8505" />
             <DstRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="5671" ySize="8505" />
          </SimpleSource>
          <SimpleSource>
             <SourceFilename relativeToVRT="1">CF05_GeoTifv1-01.tif</SourceFilename>
             <SourceBand>2</SourceBand>
             <SourceProperties RasterXSize="5671" RasterYSize="8505" DataType="Byte" BlockXSize="5671" BlockYSize="17" />
             <SrcRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="5671" ySize="8505" />
             <DstRect xOff="5669" yOff="0" xSize="5671" ySize="8505" />
          </SimpleSource>
       </VRTRasterBand>
       <VRTRasterBand dataType="Byte" band="3">
          <HideNoDataValue>1</HideNoDataValue>
          <ColorInterp>Blue</ColorInterp>
          <SimpleSource>
             <SourceFilename relativeToVRT="1">CF04_GeoTifv1-02.tif</SourceFilename>
             <SourceBand>3</SourceBand>
             <SourceProperties RasterXSize="5671" RasterYSize="8505" DataType="Byte" BlockXSize="5671" BlockYSize="17" />
             <SrcRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="5671" ySize="8505" />
             <DstRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="5671" ySize="8505" />
          </SimpleSource>
          <SimpleSource>
             <SourceFilename relativeToVRT="1">CF05_GeoTifv1-01.tif</SourceFilename>
             <SourceBand>3</SourceBand>
             <SourceProperties RasterXSize="5671" RasterYSize="8505" DataType="Byte" BlockXSize="5671" BlockYSize="17" />
             <SrcRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="5671" ySize="8505" />
             <DstRect xOff="5669" yOff="0" xSize="5671" ySize="8505" />
          </SimpleSource>
       </VRTRasterBand>
       <VRTRasterBand dataType="Byte" band="4">
          <ColorInterp>Alpha</ColorInterp>
          <ComplexSource>
             <SourceFilename relativeToVRT="1">CF04_GeoTifv1-02.tif</SourceFilename>
             <SourceBand>1</SourceBand>
             <SourceProperties RasterXSize="5671" RasterYSize="8505" DataType="Byte" BlockXSize="5671" BlockYSize="17" />
             <SrcRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="5671" ySize="8505" />
             <DstRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="5671" ySize="8505" />
             <ScaleOffset>255</ScaleOffset>
             <ScaleRatio>0</ScaleRatio>
          </ComplexSource>
          <ComplexSource>
             <SourceFilename relativeToVRT="1">CF05_GeoTifv1-01.tif</SourceFilename>
             <SourceBand>1</SourceBand>
             <SourceProperties RasterXSize="5671" RasterYSize="8505" DataType="Byte" BlockXSize="5671" BlockYSize="17" />
             <SrcRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="5671" ySize="8505" />
             <DstRect xOff="5669" yOff="0" xSize="5671" ySize="8505" />
             <ScaleOffset>255</ScaleOffset>
             <ScaleRatio>0</ScaleRatio>
          </ComplexSource>
       </VRTRasterBand>
    </VRTDataset>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert the file to WGS84

```
gdalwarp in_test.vrt out_test.vrt -t_srs "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84"
```

Calculate the bbox with GDAL in Python

```
import gdal
    
ds = gdal.Open('out_test.vrt')

cols = ds.RasterXSize
rows = ds.RasterYSize

geotransform = ds.GetGeoTransform()
bb1 = originX = geotransform[0]
bb4 = originY = geotransform[3]

pixelWidth = geotransform[1]
pixelHeight = geotransform[5]

Width = cols*pixelWidth
Height = rows*pixelHeight

bb3 = originX+Width
bb2 = originY+Height

print str(bb1) + ',' + str(bb2) + ',' + str(bb3) + ',' + str(bb4)
```

Which results in a bbox for your sample file

```
>>> 166.31571873,-46.1983972613,166.969160112,-45.841900527
```